# Decision tree overfit test

Tags: python, classification, data-science, decision-tree

I am currently working with data that is easy to overfit, so i made function with testing roc_auc score for each depth as i read on sklearn that max_depth is usually the reason for tree to overfit. But i am not sure if my thinking is correctly here there is pic of my result:

[image: My roc_auc vs depth graph]

[image: xgb and rfc graphs]

I was also trying to ust postpruning method, but my graph looked quite different from others i found at internet so i am not sure what it gives me

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html). The basic idea is simple: you split your dataset into a training and validation (or testing) sets. Then you train a model on the training set and test it on the validation set. If your model is overfitted, it will perform well on training set but poorly on validation set. In this case it's best to decrease model complexity or add so-called regularization (e.g. tree pruning). Perhaps, the simplest way to perform cross-validation in SciKit Learn is to use `cross_val_score` function as described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics).

**Note 1:** In some context (e.g. in neural networks) there are both - validation and test sets (in addition to the train set). I won't go into the detail here, but don't be confused with these terms in different contexts.

**Note 2:** Cross-validation is such a standard thing that it even gave a name to another StackExchange site - [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), where you may get more answers about statistics. Another and perhaps even more appropriate site has a self-explaining name - [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for answer, i actually generated those graphs with cross_val_score with cv=10, so looking at my results i can guess my algorithms aren't overfitted?

Comment: Ah, I think I saw only subset of images when I was writing the answer, so it got not very relevant, sorry :) Yes, if train and test metrics are close, it usually means you don't have overfitting (assuming your samples are independent). Your images 1, 3 and 4 look like no overfitting, model at image 2 looks overfitted though. Also, your image 4 looks understandable. Do you have concernes about it?

Comment: I saw few graphs with por pruning and in every with higher alpha test set was gaining accuracy, and in mine its starting from 1, thats why i have concerns about it.

Comment: From other graphs I understand your data is pretty simple and the model learned it (and generalized) pretty well. That's why even without pruning your get high accuracy for both - train and test sets. In more complex cases if a tree is built fully, it tends to overfit and thus accuracy on train set starts high, while accuracy on test starts low. After some pruning (which gives generalization to unseen data) train accuracy drops, while test accuracy increases. And so we get plots like [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_cost_complexity_pruning_003.png).

Comment: Oh okay i get it, one more little question maybe you know answer to that, im curious about features with very imbalanced distribution, where i have 1 atribute with 80% and then 2-3 with very low %, can/should i drop  those columns (thats what i did).

Comment: Do you mean that you have binary attributes, 1 of them is true in 80% cases, and others are mostly false?

Comment: Not sure if they are false, but for example i have ring-color of mushroom with values c-80% of all, y, g -10%. Does it affect models performance? Or it will affect it only if for example for g 100% outcomes is the same (its binary classification)

Comment: So they are categorical variables with some dominant value. You shouldn't remove any values then, just use the data as it is. If your attribute has value `g` in 10% of cases, but 99% of these cases describe the same class, then it's a great feature to distinguish a particular class from the others. Note that decisions trees are usually pretty much interpretable - you can look at their structure and understand how decision is made (see example [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualizing-decision-trees-with-python-scikit-learn-graphviz-matplotlib-1c50b4aa68dc)).

Comment: Just to make it clear, usually you shouldn't worry about value imbalance in independent variables, but be careful with class imbalance, e.g. when 99% of your observations belong to one class.

Comment: Thank you so much :) you helped me a lot, sory for writing in comment i cant use private chat yet :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I believe comments are designed specifically for clarification and followup questions, exactly what you posted.